# What can be done with no calculator or weather app on iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications, ios

Asking for my six year old. Her iPad has no weather app or calculator, which is apparently making her very unhappy. She can see myself and her mom using both of these apps on our iPhones, but her iPad somehow doesn't have them.

What can I do to calculate and look for weather on an iPad Air with iOS 8.1 on it?

Answer (score 3):

Apple simply haven't made iPad apps for Weather or Calculator. This is intentional and nothing you have done. Apps with similar functionality are numerous on the App Store.

Additionally, the notification center does pull a local forecast, and many extensions can add exactly the weather information you prefer rather than just using Yahoo weather like the iPhone does. There are many regions in the world where local weather apps are superior to the ones on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

On the iPad, Siri will perform math calculations and the world clock will show weather for the locations you add.